# How to open a file and call a function to parse through a list?

Tags: python

I have to go through a given file that contains jumbled up letters and pull out the unjumbled integers and append them to a new list.

I have most of the code to run through it but I don't see my mistake.

I've tried splitting lines in the file into separate strings and then running through them to append them into a large list. I've attempted using 'for each' loops, 'for' loops, and the split functions.

1. This is the function that I call beforehand.

   This function takes a string and then parses through the string return a list of numbers:

   **Input:**

   ```
   '800!)176^b006$(46$*#63Z*16$*06$z5^'
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
   [800, 600, 64, 63, 61, 60]
   ```

   **Code:**

   ```py
   lst_num = []
       cur_num = ""
       for char in s:
           if char.isdigit():
               cur_num += char
           elif char == '$' and cur_num:
               lst_num.append(int(cur_num[::-1]))
               cur_num = ""
           elif char == '^':
               cur_num = ""
           elif not char.isdigit() and cur_num:
               lst_num.append(int(cur_num))
               cur_num = ""
       if cur_num:
           lst_num.append(int(cur_num))
       return lst_num
   ```
2. This takes an input text file and then goes through each line, parsing out the numbers and then adding them to a single list

   **Input:**

   ```py
   '800!)176^b006$(46$*#63Z*16$*06$z5^
    47$ 42^ 18$bj55,
    166^!56'
   ```

   **Expected Output:**

   ```py
   [800, 600, 64, 63, 61, 60, 74, 81, 55, 56]
   ```

   **Code:**

   ```py
   def parse_file(filename):
       big_nums = []
       with open(filename, 'r') as f:
           for line in f:
               chars = line.split(',')
               for char in chars:
                    combine = parse_line(char)
               big_nums.append(combine)
   ```

   **Actual Output**:

   ```
   [[800, 600, 64, 63, 61, 60], [74, 81, 55], [56]]
   ```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you mean `range(len(chars))` by chance?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, you need to make a [mre] including input, and if there's an error message, you need to include the traceback. [ask] has more helpful tips.

Comment: Your first code snippet looks like its missing a piece.

Comment: Also, why are you splitting on commas? Your input appears to only contain a single one.

Answer (score 2):

`chars` is a list, so `range(chars)` is invalid. You probably meant `range(len(chars))`, but it's easier to just iterate through `chars` directly:

```
for char in chars:
    big_nums.append(char)
```

or use `list.extend` instead:

```
big_nums.extend(chars)
```

But note this still won't give your expected output because it returns a list of strings, not ints.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I am not getting the error. And now it returns most of what I want, but now its in one big list with mini lists.

Comment: @Arturo You might have written `.append(chars)` by accident

Comment: This is what I get now:
   `[[800, 600, 64, 63, 61, 60], [74, 81, 55], [56]]`

Comment: But I want them all together in a list, not as individual lists within each other

Comment: @Arturo I can't help with that unless you make a [mre]

Comment: @Arturo Comments don't support code blocks. Either [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58666960/edit) or ask a new question.